# Refresh/Update a report page with checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, oracle-apex, submit-button

I am using APex 4.2. I have a page with a shuttle list, (page 31), where a user can select some job categories (e, a, c, x, etc). The user can then click a button, (Generate Report), and it will take them to a page (Page 27) where a report is displayed. Each row of the report has a checkbox that is defaulted to yes (starts off checked).

The report query is along these lines:

```
select 'Y' as Selector, name, id, etc
from table
where  (instr(':'||:P31_JOB_CATEGORY||':',':'||JOB_CATEGORY||':') > 0)
```

where `P31_JOB_CATEGORY` represents the shuttle list.
I am passing the value of the shuttle list (`P31_JOB_CATEGORY`) to page 27, therefore having the actual query to the report on page 27.

I ultimately have a two part question.

1. Once the user views the report, they will see that each row is
   checked and will be able to uncheck specific rows if neccessary.
   Once they done checking/unchecking, the report should be
   saved/submitted/refreshed with their made changes that will take
   them to another page to see the report. I am having trouble
   accomplishing this on button click.
2. Ultimately their changes will need to be seen on a pdf report,
   where once they click the refresh button, the report will update
   with their changes and then possibly redirect to a page that opens
   up an open/save pdf report. But first I need to tackle refreshing
   the page with the changes they made to the report by
   checking/unchecking specific rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1/ Don't make multi-question questions. Split them up. As you indicate yourself: resolve your first issue first, then move on to the next.   2/ So what you actually want to do is to handle records which have been selected by checking the checkboxes? Is this a report or a tabular form (since you wrote "with their made changes")?

Comment: In a senese yes. I want to handle the records that have remained selected, as they are defaulted to 'selected' upon the report loading. This is a report.

Comment: Can you specify how you added a checkbox to the report? Did you use the "column selector" you can create through the report attributes or did you manually add it through the sql?

Comment: it was manually added to the sql